# if A × B ⊆ C × D then how to prove that A ⊆ C or B ⊆ D.

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Suppose $A,B,C,D$ are sets such that $A \times B \subseteq C \times D$. How do I prove that $A \subseteq C$ or $B \subseteq D$?

I am only arriving at $(x,y)$ belongs to $A \times B\to (x,y)$ belongs to $C \times D\to x$ belongs to $C$ and $Y$ belongs to $D\to A\subseteq C$ and $B\subseteq D$.

Answer (score 4):

If either $A$ or $B$ is an empty set, then $\emptyset\subseteq C$ and $\emptyset \subseteq D$, so we know the statement is true.

Let's assume that none of the sets $A,B$ is empty, i.e. there exists $a\in A, b\in B$. Take any $x\in A$. Then, because $b\in B$, we know that $(x,b)\in A\times B$, and because $A\times B\subseteq C\times D$, we know that $(x,b)\in C\times D$.

From $(x,b)\in C\times D$, we know that $x\in C$. Therefore, any element of $A$ is also an element of $C$, so $A\subseteq C$. Similarly, you show that $B\subseteq D$.

Bottom line:

If $A$ and $B$ are nonempty, then $A\subseteq C$ and $B\subseteq D$. If one, for example $B$, is empty, then $B\subseteq D$, however, in that case, $A\subseteq C$ **need not be true**.

Comment: there is no need to distinguished the case the sets non empty or empty !... As you may know, let $x\in X$ implies that what you will say is true, when $X$ is empty...

Comment: @RobertGreen Not true. If $A=C=D=\emptyset$ and $B=\{0\}$, then $A\times B = \emptyset \subseteq \emptyset = C\times D$, even though $B\subseteq D$ is *not* true.

Comment: @robertgreen My answer is not wrong, please remove your downvote.

Comment: @RobertGreen If $A$ and $B$ are non-empty, then both $A\subseteq C$ and $B\subseteq D$ is true. If you do not assume that they are non-empty, then one of the statements may not be true.

Comment: Robert Green you are wrong, you must consider the empty set as a different case here. For example $A=B=\{x\}$ and $C=\{1,2,3\}$ and $D$ is the empty set.

Comment: @RobertGreen I edited my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose $A\not\subseteq C$ and $B\not\subseteq D$. Then you have an $x\in A$ such that $x\not\in C$ and a $y\in B$ such that $y\not\in D$. Then $(x,y)\in A\times B$, and $(x,y) \not\in C\times D$, that is : $A\times B\not\subseteq C\times D$, which is a contradiction.

Comment: You have $A\subseteq B$? No you don't.

Comment: @5xum I'm sorry but $\subseteq$ means included or equal, and it is the exactly the same as $\subset$.

Comment: @RobertGreen I agree. But $A\subseteq B$ is not true.

Comment: I removed my downvote, but your answer fails if either $C$ or $D$ is an empty set.

Comment: "Then, there exists $(x,y)\in A\times B$ such that $(x,y)\notin C\times D$" does not follow from $A\times B\subseteq C\times D$ if $A\times B$ is empty.

Comment: Also, you assumed that $A\times B\not\subseteq C\times D$ and arrived at a contradiction, which is not what you do in a proof by contradiction. You should assume that $(A\subseteq C\vee B\subseteq D)$ is not true, and then reach a contradiction.

Comment: You still say "then you have an $x\in A$", so you still implicitly know that $A$ is not empty. Also, yes, I agree, this proof avoids directly stating that $A$ is nonempty, but it is a completely different proof than the one I made, so I wouldn't say that the non-emptiness in my proof is "redundant".

Comment: No, my downvote is removed.

Answer (score 0):

Proving $p \Rightarrow q$ by proving $\neg q \Rightarrow \neg p$:

If $A, B, C, D$ are sets with
$$
A \not\subseteq C \wedge B \not\subseteq D
$$
then we can choose $a^* \in A$ and $b^* \in B$ with $a^* \not\in C$ and $b^* \not\in D$.

Note that: $A \not\subseteq C$ implies $A \ne \emptyset$ (otherwise violation of $\emptyset \subseteq M$ for any set $M$) and $C \ne \emptyset$  (otherwise violation of $M \subseteq \emptyset \Rightarrow M = \emptyset$) thus some $a \in A$ and some $c \in C$ exist and the existence of at least one $a \in A$ with $a \not\in C$ (otherwise violation of $A \neq C$).

Then $(a^*, b^*) \in A \times B$ but $(a^*, b^*) \not\in C \times D$, this means $A \times B \not\subseteq C \times D$.

Comment: You cannot choose $a^*\in A$ if $A$ is empty...

Comment: It sort of is, but as it is written now, it is not made clear that you *can* choose any element $a^*\in A$.

Comment: That seems good, I just think that this should be included in an answer.